# why is media player starts more than once and media player won't stop in button click which started at on create?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to add background music to my android application. I have declared the MediaPlayer object as a class variable and create it inside oncreate(). I have start the MediPlayer object also inside the oncreate(). I have stop the media player in a button click method which starts a new intent. My requirement is to play the music when starts the layout and stop it when starts the next layout, but now it starts more than once and won't stop. Here is my code.

```
 MediaPlayer  startMusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        startMusic= MediaPlayer.create(Cover.this, R.raw.startgame);

        if(!(startMusic.isPlaying()))
        {
            startMusic.start();
        }
    }


 public  void  btnStartClick(View v)
    {
        startMusic.pause();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ScaleExercise.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong here(ASAP). 
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 static  MediaPlayer  startMusic;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    startMusic= MediaPlayer.create(Cover.this, R.raw.startgame);


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(!(startMusic.isPlaying()))
    {   
        startMusic.setLooping(true);
        startMusic.start();
    }

    super.onStart();

}

 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startMusic.stop();
    super.onStop();

}
public  void  btnStartClick(View v)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ScaleExercise.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it as above and now i can hear that background music is playing only once but there is this error which displays on the device screen as "Unfortunately app has stooped" and in logcat as
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.kushi.exercisegame2/com.example.kushi.exercisegame2.Cover} did not call through to super.onStart()
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5338)

Comment: oh,forgot to call super.onstart(),ive edited the code,and to play music continuously you only have to set player's loop method to true